# Salesforce and Mailchimp integration

Tags: integration, app, data-export

I have an account with mailchimp and salesforce and I want to connect both of them. Mailchimp offers an option to sync a Salesforce account to Mailchimp through a user account. I synced both tool through my user account which is a system administrator account and the sync was done correctly. When the sync is completed, Mailchimp imports all of Salesforce contacts but it only imports about 12 fields that have no relevant information to me (city, state, etc..). I need to import all fields from my contacts in Salesforce to Mailchimp.

Answer (score 3):

Yea I think the mailchimp sync doesn't support syncing of custom fields unfortunately.  One possible way around it is that you can filter your queries by custom fields, so you could build different lists that represent field values, depending on how complex your needs are.

More info here: 
http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/what-is-mailchimp-for-salesforce